# For each row in a df, I want to calculate the sum of consecutive four values till last value in python?

Tags: python

I have a df,

```
     A      B     C     D      E     F   G
     1      2    3     4      4     5   5
    100   100   Na    100   100    10  5
```

I want to create a df, that calculates the consecutive sum,that is 1+2+3+4 = D, 2+3+4+4 = E .... If na is there, the output should be na.

Output:

```
       D     E     F      G
       10    13    16     18  
       na    na    na     215
```

When I tried it takes every 4 values, kindly help

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) and filter the output with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
N = 4
out = df.rolling(N, axis=1).sum().iloc[:, N-1:]
```

Note that `axis=1` will be deprecated in the future, at which point you should use a [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
N = 4
out = df.T.rolling(N).sum().iloc[N-1:].T
```

Output:

```
      D     E     F      G
0  10.0  13.0  16.0   18.0
1   NaN   NaN   NaN  215.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It was very hard for me to come up with a solution because you didn't share any source code. Finally, I have come up with a solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': [1, 100], 'B': [2, 100], 'C': [3, np.nan], 'D': [4, 100],
        'E': [4, 100], 'F': [5, 10], 'G': [5, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
consecutive_sums = df.rolling(window=4, min_periods=4, axis=1).sum()
consecutive_sums[consecutive_sums.isna().all(axis=1)] = np.nan
consecutive_sums = consecutive_sums.iloc[:, 3:]
print(consecutive_sums)
```